# How to replace a list of numbers (or times/timestamps) with their sum?

Tags: search, replace

For example, this text:

```
2:26
3:04
3:14
5:38
4:12
10:30
6:29
6:53
11:49
9:33
4:17
7:49
6:10
6:04
6:28
6:40
4:21
```

(These are actually minute:second format, not hour:minute, if it matters.  So ideally the sum would compute hours from the total minutes and give the answer hours:minutes:seconds.)

I know there are ways to do this in `bash`, e.g. with `awk`.  Running an external shell command is okay, but it has to work *from within* vi—and a vim-native approach would be preferred.

Comment: I suspect that because they are times instead of integers, this specific action may have to be done with a shell command.  But it seems that simply adding *integers* should be possible natively in vim....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One powerful function of vim is piping an area thru an external command.

(I think this is not what you are looking for, but, just for the record):

```
:%!awk -F: '{a=$2*60+$1} END {printf("\%d:\%02d",a/60,a\%60)}'
```

---

\thanks{Wildcard} for pointing out the "`10:09`" problem and solution

Comment: After some months more experience, this is how I would resolve it today as well.  Shouldn't there be a width specifier on the second `%d`, though?  So that e.g. `11:09` won't be written as `11:9`?

Comment: @wildcard, thank you: you are absolutely right. (fixed)

Answer (score 2):

The following are a function and a command that can be used with a range to achieve your goal.

```
command! -range Sum call s:sum()

function! s:sum() range
  " Get range boundaries
  let l1 = getpos("'<")[1]
  let l2 = getpos("'>")[1]
  if l2 <= l1 | return | endif

  " Calculate sum of seconds in provided range of lines
  let sum = 0
  for time in map(getline(l1,l2), 'split(v:val, '':'')')
    let sum += time[0]*60 + time[1]
  endfor

  " Delete lines and calculate time in format hh:mm:ss
  normal! gvd
  call setline(l1, printf('%02d:%02d:%02d',
        \ sum/3600,
        \ (sum % 3600)/60,
        \ sum % 60))
endfunction
```

To use this in your given example, you would simply do something like this: `ggV}:Sum<cr>`. You may also map the command, e.g.

```
vnoremap <leader>s :Sum<cr>
nnoremap <leader>s gv:Sum<cr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with, Karl was faster to post something more elegant but as I spend some time on it I think it couldn't hurt to share it :-)

```
" Takes a string formatted H:M:S and convert it to seconds
function! ConvertToSecond(time)
    let l:cmp = split(a:time, ":")
    let l:seconds = 0

    if (len(l:cmp) == 1)
        let l:seconds = l:cmp[0]
    elseif (len(l:cmp) == 2)
        let l:seconds = l:cmp[1] + 60*l:cmp[0]
    elseif (len(l:cmp) == 3)
        let l:seconds = l:cmp[2] + 60*l:cmp[1] + 3600*l:cmp[0]
    endif

    return l:seconds
endfunction

" Takes a number of seconds and convert it to h:m:s
function! ConvertFromSeconds(time)
    let l:time     = a:time
    let l:hours    = l:time / 3600
    let l:time     = l:time % 3600
    let l:minutes  = l:time / 60
    let l:time     = l:time % 60
    let l:seconds  = l:time

    return l:hours . "h" . l:minutes . "m" . l:seconds . "s"
endfunction

" Iterate through line and append the sum on the next line
function! SumAndConvert() range
    let l:total = 0

    if (a:firstline > a:lastline)
        echo "Wrong range"
        return
    endif

    let l:line = a:firstline
    " Read lines from current one to last one
    while (l:line <= a:lastline)
        let l:total  = l:total + ConvertToSecond(getline(l:line))
        let l:line   += 1
    endwhile

    normal '> 
    put = ConvertFromSeconds(l:total)
endfunction
```

It can be called with a range like this for all the file:

```
:1,$call SumAndConvert()
```

or this for the last visual selection:

```
:'<,'>call SumAndConvert()
```

And of course it is possible to create user-defined commands to shorten the call.

Answer (score 2):

With [lh-vim-lib](http://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib) function `lh#list#accumulate()`, and the following definition:

```
function! ToSeconds(ms)
  let l = split(a:ms, ':')
  return l[0] * 60 + l[1]
endfunction
```

it can be done with:

```
echo strftime('%H:%M:%S', eval(lh#list#accumulate(getline(1,'$'), 'ToSeconds', 'join(v:1_, "+")')))
```

If you want to make it a command, it could be:

```
function! ToSeconds(ms)
  let l = split(a:ms, ':')
  return l[0] * 60 + l[1]
endfunction

command! -range=% -narg=0 SumMinSec
      \ echo strftime('%H:%M:%S', eval(lh#list#accumulate(getline(<line1>, <line2>), 'ToSeconds', 'join(v:1_, "+")')))
```

NB: As you see, no need for modulo operation, we already have `strftime`. However we lack `strptime`, hence my `ToSeconds()` function.

---

Or, a more *simple* solution:

```
command! -range=% -narg=0 SumMinSec
  \ echo strftime('%H:%M:%S',
  \     lh#list#accumulate2(
  \        lh#list#chain_transform(
  \           getline(<line1>, <line2>),
  \           ['split(v:1_, ":")', 'v:1_[0]*60 + v:1_[1]']),
  \        0))
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way, but here is the hacky native solution I used.  It won't work as written if any of the numbers are zeros, e.g., 5:00 or 0:30.

```
:set nrformats-=octal

# TYPE the following in insert mode, don't execute in normal mode:
0"hdwx"mdwj0:let @a='^Rh^A$^Rm^A'^M@a

# (you can't record playing another macro.)
# To type the ^R etc. sequences, prefix them with ^V

# Then yank the line into register q with <Esc>0"qy$

# Type the following in insert mode on a new line:
$60^X0^A

# Then yank into register c with <Esc>0"cy$

# Next, run the following in normal mode:
16@q7@c
# The counts here are of course specific to the times I was adding.
```

Like I said, a little bit hacky, but easier than pulling out a calculator or doing it in your head (for a large list).

Comment: This solution is really note very "native", but it is hacky. It is also not very adaptible and reusable (e.g. if you overwrite `a` with another macro).

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, I'd use plain substitution with the `sub-replace-\=`, where you can enter an expression that is evaluated before doing the substitution. Things to keep in mind when using `\=` in the substitution are that special meaning for characters (in `:h sub-replace special`) does not apply and that text matched with `\( \)` need to be accessed with `submatch(1)` etc. `submatch(0)` contains the whole matched text. For full details, you can see `:h sub-replace-\=`.

Going from format `HH:MM:SS` to sum in seconds:

```
01:02:26
03:04
03:14
```

can be done with

```
:%s/\(\(\d\+\):\)\?\(\d\+\):\(\d\+\)/\=submatch(2)*3600+submatch(3)*60+submatch(4)
```

where the hours are optional. Now we have

```
3746
184
194
```

which we can yank (clearing the register first) using the command

```
:let @a="" | %y A
```

To calculate the sum to the last line, we can use `:put` in combination with the expression register `@=`

```
:$put =eval('0' . substitute(@a, '\n', '+', 'g') . '0')
```

where we substitute newlines in the register with `+` signs using the function `substitute()`. The register also contains newlines in the beginning and at the end, so we need to pad it with zeroes on both ends. This results in

```
3746
184
194
4124
```

To go in the other direction (from seconds to `HH:MM:SS`), you can do

```
:%s@\d\+@\=printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", submatch(0)/3600, submatch(0)%3600/60, submatch(0)%60)
```

where you need to use some other character than `/` as a delimiter, since it is used in the expression. I chose to use `@`. In the end, we get

```
01:02:26
00:03:04
00:03:14
01:08:44
```

Comment: This looks like the solution I was looking for, but it's a little bit unclear.  Can you explain it a bit more?  For instance, why `submatch(2)` instead of just `\2` like I use in a typical replace command?

Comment: I updated the answer. After `\=` the escaped characters such as `\2` don't have their special meaning anymore, but you can use submatch(2) instead to get around that.

Comment: This does not compute the sum of the list of times. It simply converts a time in one format to another. If this does answer your question, then the question should be rephrased.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg, thanks for clarifying the question for me! I had misunderstood it simply as wanting to calculate row-wise sums in seconds.